# Cannot update meta viewport tag

Tags: iphone, ipad, orientation, viewport

I am trying to update the content attribute of the viewport tag based on the user's device and orientation of that device.

I have no problems reading the device type and its orientation, so I run script to create the meta tag dynamically based on those results.

My problem is when the user updates orientation from landscape to portrait (or vice versa) I cannot update the content attribute.

My goal is to swap between these two values:

//Portrait
    .setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width; maximum-scale=0.75; user-scalable=1;');

//Landscape
    .setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=1;');

I've searched far and wide for a solution to this answer. I hope someone knows the trick behind this.

**Edit**

What I was trying to accomplish should be done with css and not using the metatags, like ceejayoz has commented below, you can do this with media queries.

```
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait) { 
   // insert code here
}
```

Comment: I'd imagine they're not read dynamically. Why do you want to do this anyways?

Comment: I was trying to create a specific viewport for each orientation of the ipad.

Comment: Can't you just use a media query to adjust size/width/etc.? `@media only screen and (orientation:portrait) { }`

Comment: That seems like an appropriate alternative. Thank you!